# knockout bootstrap not on load

Tags: knockout.js, bootstrap-multiselect, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a knockout.js-based site.
I have a tags-input filed an a multiple select element.
All works fine, if they are shown at load.
But I want to show them just if the user clicks a button.

How can I do that?

Thanks

```
<!-- ko if: state=="EDIT" -->
//the default state is not that. Here should appear the tagsinput, but if it's here, don't works
<!-- /ko -->
<input id="domains" type="text" value="" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Add tags" />
```

Comment: Can you show us that part of your code? General answer: set the visibility on click?

Answer (score 1):

`state` must be an observable (`ko.observable()`), and you need to *call* it to get its value: `if: state() === 'EDIT'`.

Example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  state: ko.observable("DEFAULT")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: state() === "EDIT" -->
<h1> Edit section </h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: state() === "DEFAULT" -->
<h1> Default section </h1>
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: state.bind(null, 'EDIT')">Edit</button>
<button data-bind="click: state.bind(null, 'DEFAULT')">Default</button>
```

Comment: I see all other thing in edit mode, the textinput is appears, too, but it doesn't have the formatting, and don't works.

Comment: If your text input field has some sort of editing library you must write a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for that library.

Comment: The `if` binding removes/adds elements from the DOM, potentially breaking any previously initialized third-party widgets. You could try to replace it for a `visible` binding. This binding does not remove the element, which might suit you better. Note that @Tomalak 's comment is still true: any widgets should be handled via custom binding handlers.

Comment: Additionally, if you have only two states it will be much simpler and more logical if you would use an observable named `editEnabled` which contains `true` or `false`.